dbt_project as_bool not working as expected
I have a dbt_project file that looks like this
name: "project"
version: 1.0.0
config-version: 2

profile: default

vars:
  model:
    enabled: "{{ target.name == 'test' | as_bool }}"

But it keeps complaining -
Parsing Error
  at path ['enabled']: 'False' is not of type 'boolean'

Any pointer would be appreciated.
I used this - https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/dbt-jinja-functions/as_bool -  as reference. I also tried converting to lower before bool but that didnt work either.
I have tried the following variations
    enabled: "{{ (target.name == 'test') | as_bool }}" -- gives the same error 
    enabled: {{ (target.name == 'test') | as_bool }} -- gives compilation error



I haven't tested it, but have you tried either of these?

enabled: "{{ (target.name == 'test') | as_bool }}"
enabled: {{ (target.name == 'test') | as_bool }}


You're defining a variable but not showing how you're using it. Can you include the piece of code that references this var?

Try removing quotes, you need to get False, not "False".
I've tested it a little to make sure it compiles and works this time.
What you need are parenthesis for the condition, so your code should be:
enabled: "{{ (target.name == 'test') | as_bool }}"

instead of
enabled: "{{ target.name == 'test' | as_bool }}"


that just throws a compilation error -
`
Raw Error:
while constructing a mapping
in "", line 13, column 14
found unhashable key
in "", line 13, column 15
`
